# Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFound: org.springframework.util.comparator.InvertibleComparator

Tags: swagger, migration, openapi

Caused by:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry': factory bean threw exception on object creation

I have recently upgraded swagger to openAPI.
Dependencies:
Springframework:3.1.2
Java-17
springdoc-openAPI-starter-webmvc-ui-2.1.0

Can someone help me with this?

I have commented all swagger dependencies and swagger annotations also. But still same issue